# Subsetting data in shiny server.R file

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to get a simple Shiny app to work (this would be the start of something bigger). My problem is that subsetting data in the sever.R part of the app does not seem to work at all for me.

The error message is:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'localA3' not found

Here's my server.R file:

```
# server.R

library(ggmap)
library(scales)
library(grid)

localA <- read.csv("local7.csv", header=TRUE)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    output$map <- renderPlot({

      sub <- switch(input$sub, 
                    "a" = "a",
                    "b" = "b",
                    "c" = "c")


      opt <- switch(input$opt, 
                    "data" = "data",
                    "obs" = "obs")


      localx = reactive({
        x <- subset(localA, factor==paste(sub))
        return(x)
      })

      localA3 <- localx()

      testmapA <- qmap("England", zoom = 6, color = "bw", legend = "topleft")

      testmapA +
        geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour = localA3$opt, size = localA3$opt),   data = localA3)

    })
  }
)
```

...and this is my UI.R file:

```
# UI.R

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("A Shiny Example"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Create maps with random data for UK local authorities."),

      selectInput("sub", 
                  label = "Choose a category to display",
                  choices = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  selected = "a"),

      selectInput("opt", 
                  label = "Choose a variable to display",
                  choices = c("data", "obs"),
                  selected = "data"),


      sliderInput("range", 
                  label = "Range of interest:",
                  min = 0, max = 100, value = c(0, 100))
    ),

    mainPanel(plotOutput("map"))
  )
))
```

For whatever reason R tells me that it can't find the object 'localA3'. I have tried to program the subsetting part of the code in many different ways now - from reactive expressions over functions to simple R-code. What works outside of Shiny doesn't work in the server.R program.

Can anyone give me any hints on what I might be doing wrong?

The first ten entries of my base dataset 'local7.csv' are as follows:

```
    lon         lat         data        obs         factor
1   -0.1277583  51.5073509  87.828234   20.49259318 a
2   0.1293497   51.5464828  68.79663358 98.0480588  a
3   -0.1997     51.6444     24.35460542 76.77994522 b
4   0.154327    51.439933   71.51349632 28.05491455 a
5   -0.2710568  51.5672808  91.31933313 69.15576621 c
6   0.013156    51.406025   57.98920169 56.12171479 a
7   -0.1588255  51.5517059  45.68928313 29.73514486 a
8   -0.098234   51.376165   29.47027315 96.1460748  b
9   -0.3415002  51.5250257  36.46005588 76.66948508 c
10  -0.0837     51.6516     43.57721438 50.65123884 c
```

Comment: `localx()` to `localx`?

Comment: Thanks. I think I have tried this already, will check as soon as possible. Unfortunately the Google API let's me down at the moment (403 error code - will fix itself eventually).

Comment: @jazzurro, since `localx` is a reactive expression it must be called with `localx()` in the Shiny framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `aes` call to `aes_string` and make all elements strings so you are consistent with `geom_point`.  Before you are using both objects and strings.  The following small change at the end of you uiR works for me.

```
testmapA +
          geom_point(aes_string(x = "lon", y = "lat", colour = input$opt, size = input$opt),   data = localA3)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really interesting. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to do the trick for me. I get another well-known error message - "Error : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class reactive". You might understand why this is slowly driving me nuts... Best

Comment: Oh no - wait a sec - IT WORKS!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH. I had tried out jazzurro's tip above in the code - and that stopped it from working when I tried your tip above. Am very grateful!

Comment: @Jan, glad to help.  If this satisfies you, please accept the answer.

Comment: Done - you're a legend!